# How could I understand if migration goes UP or DOWN in ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a migration which should have these lines of code:

```
if up? do
  execute "some sql"
else
  execute "controversial sql"
end
```

How can I do that?

P.S. My migration is too big to write `up` & `down`, it will be logically defective if I split it into two

Answer (score 2):

Use `direction/0` inside your migration

```
if direction() == :up do
  execute "some sql"
else # :down
  execute "controversial sql"
end
```